# How to get average of last N numbers in a stream with static memory

Tags: math, average

I have a stream of numbers and in every cycle I need to count the average of last N of them. This can be, of course, solved using an array where I store the last N numbers and in every cycle I shift it, add the new one and count the average.

```
N = 3

+---+-----+
| a | avg |
+---+-----+
| 1 |     |
| 2 |     |
| 3 | 2.0 |
| 4 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 3.3 |
| 3 | 3.3 |
| 5 | 3.7 |
| 4 | 4.0 |
| 5 | 4.7 |
+---+-----+
```

First N numbers (where there "isn't enough data for counting the average") doesn't interest me much, so the results there may be anything/undefined.

My question is, can this be done without using an array, that is, with static amount of memory? If so, then how?

I'll do the coding myself - I just need to know the theory.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt you can do it without an array, but you can speed it up by maintaining the sum. Then you only need to add one and subtract one number instead of recomputing the entire sum.

Comment: Finding the cumulative sum and at the same time counting the numbers. If the count is large and the numbers' range is narrow, then I doubt loosing one or two numbers will shift the mean considerably.

Comment: @macroland I don't understand what you mean. The count is indeed large, but the numbers' range may be also large. Specifically, the range is around 0 - 10^6 and it can go from zero to top in about 2*N consecutive numbers.

Comment: If `N` itself is dynamic, then I don't know how you can do this with a static amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this as a black box containing some state. If you control the input stream, you can draw conclusions on the state. In your sliding window array-based approach, it is kind of obvious that if you feed a bunch of zeros into the algorithm after the original input, you get a bunch of averages with a decreasing number of non-zero values taken into account. The last one has just one original non-zero value, so if you multiply that my *N* you get the last input back. Using that and the second-to-last output which accounts for two non-zero inputs, you can reconstruct the second-to-last input, and so on.

So essentially your algorithm needs to maintain sufficient state to reconstruct the last *N* elements of input, at least if you formulate it as an on-line algorithm. I don't think an off-line algorithm can do any better, except if you consider it reading the input multiple times, but I don't have as strong an agument for that.

Of course, in some theoretical models you can avoid the array and e.g. encode all the state into a single arbitrary length integer, but that's just cheating the theory, and doesn't make any difference in practice.